# Avoid table view didSelectRowIndexPath action while main thread is blocked

Tags: ios

I have a problem. In my app action sheet with picker opens when table's row tapped.
My problem is that action sheet dose not opens while main thread is blocked but touch event are added in run loop therefore, whenever main thread gets a change it completes all touches action as a result action sheet opens according to the number of times we tapped on table row. But I want this only once.

How to fix this problem???

Comment: Why is the main thread "*blocked*"?

Comment: UI is always on the main queue, so you simply should never block the main queue. So, your question really should be "how do I do perform these db operations without blocking the main queue?" (of course, including appropriate code samples).

Answer (score 1):

The main thread should never be "*blocked*"... Try running whatever is "*blocking*" the main thread on a different thread by doing the following.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [self doSomeLongTask]; // 1
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self longTaskDidFinish]; // 2
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for ur reply.but, I am unable to do it bcz DB operations are executing at that time on main thread